# Trying to update entry but getting error "Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sql-update

I'm new to python and Flask, I'm having an issue with updating a field entry, I can add 2 fields in a user profile and saves data to their user page,  also I'm able to delete that entry, but when trying to update the "Tips" field, it comes back as a 'Bad Request' error;  files are:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, InstrumentForm, IdeasForm
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///Mix_Tips.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), index =True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), index = True, unique = True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))
    idea = db.relationship('Ideas', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
        return '<N'

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password_hash(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)


class Tips(db.Model):
    Instrument = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key = True)
    Frequency_Boost = db.Column(db.String(200), index =True, unique=True)
    Frequency_Cut = db.Column(db.String(200), index =True, unique = True)
    Advice = db.Column(db.String(500))

class Ideas(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    Instrument = db.Column(db.String(50))
    Tips = db.Column(db.String(200))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tricks {}>'.format(self.Tips)


    
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
  form = LoginForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
    if user and user.check_password_hash(form.password.data):
      login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
      return redirect(url_for('user', username = form.username.data))
    if user is None or not user.check_password_hash(form.password.data):
      flash('Invalid username or password')
  return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route('/user/<username>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def user(username):
    user = current_user
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=user.username).first()
    idea = Ideas.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
    if idea is None:
        idea = []
    form = IdeasForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        New_Idea = Ideas(Instrument = form.Instrument.data, Tips = form.Tips.data, user_id=current_user.id)
        db.session.add(New_Idea)
        db.session.commit()
        print(request.form.get('Tips'))
    return render_template('user.html', user=user, form=form, idea=idea)



@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update(id):
    tip_to_update = Ideas.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tip_to_update.Tips = request.form['Tips']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user))
    else:
        return render_template('update.html', tip_to_update=tip_to_update)


@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id): 
    idea_to_delete = Ideas.query.get_or_404(id)
    try:
        db.session.delete(idea_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user))
    except:
        return "Problem Deleting"


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id): 
    return User.query.get(int(id))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))



**user.html:**

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<center><h1 style="color:rgb(41, 15, 135)">Welcome back {{current_user.username }}!</h1></center>
<center><h2 style="color:rgb(41, 15, 135)">Music Mixing Guide</h2></center>
<h3 style="color:rgb(69, 67, 67)">Add your Instrument and Specific Tips for Mixing below:</h3>
<form action="user" method='POST'>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<p 
    style="color:rgb(52, 52, 52)">{{form.Instrument.label}} <br>
    {{form.Instrument(size=30)}} 

</p>
<p
    style="color:rgb(52, 52, 52)">{{form.Tips.label}} <br>
    {{form.Tips(size=80)}}
</p>

<p> <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" value="Add"></p>

</form>

<br>

    <h3>Your Music Mixing Tips</h3>
    {% for tricks in idea %}
        <ol>
            <li><p style="color:rgb(41, 15, 135)"> <b><h5>Instrument:</h5></b> {{tricks.Instrument}}</li>
                <p style="color:rgb(41, 15, 135)"> <b><h5>Tip:</h5></b> {{tricks.Tips}}
        </ol>
                <p></p> <a href="/update/{{ tricks.id }}" class=" btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Update</a>
                 <a href="/delete/{{ tricks.id }}" class=" btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
                <br>
       
    {% endfor %}





<br>
<br>
<br>

<a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Log Out</a>




{% endblock %}


**update.html:**

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class='container'></div>
  <h2>Update Mix Tip</h2>
  <br>

  <form action="/update/{{tip_to_update.id}}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Tip" Tips="Tips" class="form-control" value="{{tip_to_update.Tips}}"> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
    
  </form>


</div> 
{% endblock %} 


**forms.py**

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    email=StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(message='Invalid Email'), Length(max=150)])
    password=PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=150)])
    Repeat_password=PasswordField('Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit=SubmitField('Register')
 

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password=PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=150)])
    remember_me=BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit=SubmitField('Sign In')


class InstrumentForm(FlaskForm):
    Instrument= SelectField('Instrument', choices=[('Voice'), ('Acoustic Guitar'), ('Electric Guitar'), 
    ('Bass Guitar'), ('Piano'), ('Bass Drum'), ('Snare Drum'), ('HiHats'), ('Toms'), ('Cymbals'), ('Brass')])

class IdeasForm(FlaskForm):
    Instrument = StringField('Instrument')
    Tips = StringField('Tips')
    submit= SubmitField('Add')   


    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

I think it may have something to do with the "request.form['Tips'] line in app.py, but would like to know for sure and how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

welcome mac. I'm not sure the error message, but as far as i can tell you'll need to rework your database models, your relationships to be precised. Here is an example:

```
class Ideas(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    instrument = db.Column(db.String(50))
    tips = db.relationship("Tips", lazy="dynamic")
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

have a look at the docs: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

also i recomment this flask mega tutorial from Miguel Grinberg: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice , I finally found out what was wrong , the "tip_to_update.Tips = request.form['Tips']" line in the update route should be "tip_to_update.Tips = form.Tips.data" instead , as I used the Flask Form method of collecting data in my register route, it wasn't accepting the request.form method. I'm still unable to show the data entered in the placeholder when a user wants to update a Tip, it opens the update page with a empty placeholder field to update , but I'd like the text from the entered tip to show , so the user can make a few alterations instead of typing out the whole tip again.